# Передача информации в новую активити

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Есть лента новостей из группы, я загружаю ее в RecyclerView. Теперь появилась необходимость сделать новую активити, что бы при нажатии на каждый элемент из списка, выводилась та же информация! Как в клиенте ВК. Не понимаю, как передавать эту информацию в новую активити?

приходит вот так:

```
public class RecyclerAdapterWall extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerAdapterWall.ViewHolder> {

    Context ctx;
    String owner_id;
    VKPostArray obj;
    Picasso picasso;
    private long longDate;

    public RecyclerAdapterWall(Context ctx, VKPostArray posts) {

        this.obj = posts;
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }

    public RecyclerAdapterWall(Context ctx, VKPostArray posts, String owner_id) {

        this.obj = posts;
        this.ctx = ctx;
        this.owner_id = owner_id;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item_wall, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            String profile1= obj.get(position).toString();

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Intent intent1 = new Intent(ctx, DetailPost.class);
                intent1.putExtra("key1",  profile1);
                view.getContext().startActivity(intent1);
            }
        });

        VKApiPost p = obj.get(position);

        try {
            VKAttachments att = new VKAttachments();
            att = p.attachments;
            VKApiPhoto photo = (VKApiPhoto) att.get(0);

            holder.imageWall.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            holder.textPost.setText(p.text);

            holder.news_name.setText(p.post_type);

            holder.textlikePost.setText(" " + p.likes_count);
            holder.textrepostPost.setText(" " + p.reposts_count);

            java.util.Date time = new java.util.Date((long) p.date * 1000);
            holder.textDatePost.setText(String.valueOf(time));

            picasso.with(ctx).load(photo.photo_604).into(holder.imageWall);

        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToRecyclerView(RecyclerView recyclerView) {
        super.onAttachedToRecyclerView(recyclerView);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return obj.size();
    }

    public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        Context ctx;
        CardView cv;
        TextView textlikePost;
        TextView textrepostPost;
        TextView textDatePost;
        TextView news_name;
        TextView textPost;
        ImageView imageWall, news_ava, like, repost;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view_wall);

            news_name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_name);
            textDatePost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textDatePost);
            textPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textPost);
            imageWall = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageWall);
            news_ava = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.news_ava);

            textlikePost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_likes_count);
            textrepostPost = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_reposts_count);
            like = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_like);
            repost = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_repost);

        }}
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если тебе приходит информация с VK в формате JSON (как я предполагаю), то передавай ее в Intent, перегнав в строку.

Пример:
Активити 1 (список):

```
String data = itemJsonObject.toString();
Intent intent = new Intent(...); 
intent.putStringExtra("data", data);
```

Активити 2(деталка):

```
JSONObject dataJson = getIntent().getStringExtra("data", "");
```

**Второй вариант**:

```
VKApiPost p = obj.get(position);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putExtra("text_post", p.text_post);
// ... так все поля. "text_post" - это лучше вынеси в отдельный класс
```

Этот `Bundle` передай в `Intent` и потом бери данные с него.

Пример класса для констант:

```
  class Constants {
         public static final String VK_POST_KEY = "text_post";
         // ... тут все ключи свои укажи 
  }
```

Comment: а потом ложить в name.setText(); ????

Comment: @sviter-pro покажи что приходит от ВК

Comment: Статью обновил.

Comment: приходят строки такого типа: com.vk.sdk.api.model.VKApiPost@6abe05e

Comment: @sviter-pro ну попробуй такую строку передать и на активити2 открыть

Comment: @sviter-pro не понятно что за obj у тебя в коде

Comment: Статью обновил.

Comment: @sviter-pro смотри ответ, обновил

Comment: что то на putExtra ругается....мол нет такого метода

Comment: @sviter-pro putString() или putStringExtra() - попробуй такие варианты

Comment: Этот Bundle передай в Intent и потом бери данные с него???

Что то я уже вообще ничего не соображаю...

Comment: @sviter-pro bundle - это считай коробка. В него можно положить какую-то инфо а потом достать оттуда. Bundle можно передать в Intent. Ложи в этот Bundle свою инфо и передавай в другую активити, а там извлекай

Comment: Черт его знает...приходит null;

Comment: все, заработало! спасибо огромное!

Answer (score 4):

При старте новой Activity:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, Activity.class);
intent.putExtra("keyName","value"); //укладываем строку "value" в `intent`
startActivity(intent);
```

Достаем в новой Activity переданные данные:
В `onCreate()`:

```
String value= getIntent().getStringExtra("keyName");
```

Теперь в `value` находится строка, которую вы передали в `intent`.

P. S. Ответ найден в [гугле](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=android%20pass%20data%20to%20activity) за 11 секунд.